# Find parent entity using date range filter on child entities with Hibernate Search in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

It's a Spring Boot with Hibernate Search. Underlying database is MySQL.

Main entity `Article` has a set of child entities: `Set<Price>`.

Each `Price` has a link to `Country` entity, `Store` entity, numeric `amount` and optional `date-begin` and optional `date-end`. Dates are used to present a discount for a period of time it there is any.

Is there a way to index `Article` entities in order to issue a search which will return only articles that has *active* prices (which would be "permanent" prices without dates and also prices that match date range based on current or any other given date).

For example:

```
Article #1
    Price: US, $100
    Price: DE, €100, from 2023-12-25 to 2023-12-31
    Price: IT, €100, from 2024-01-01

Article #2
    Price: DE, €50, to 2023-12-31
```

How to fetch all articles with active prices for country DE?

With date of today, expected result would be single article (#2) because first article has DE price that becomes active far in the future and should be skipped in search.

Lucene should do the job because there are many search options (not mentioned here) that would create a monster SQL queries. While indexing articles, many information is added from other linked tables like `Set<Tag>` (each article can have unlimited number of tags), `Category` name so you can search "body milk" and get also products that has no "body milk" in its own name.

Each article has separate text field `searchAid` where I put some keywords to help search process (for example, if article name is "candy bar", in search aid I put "bars" and then you get it when searching for "candy bars").

Also `Provider` names and `City` names and street names are added so you can search by address.

There are more details not to mention all.

Finaally I add all translations for `Article` name so you can search in any language and get wanted articles.

At the very beginning Hibernate was employed to do this job through `QueryDSL`, but automatically created query took 10+ seconds to run with only 100 test articles on i9 dev machine with 2x m2-SSD and 64GB DDR4.

Speaking in SQL, wanted Lucene query should meet this one which can be later extended by additonal filtering (by tags and any other needed criteria):

```
SELECT 
    JSON_EXTRACT(art.name, '$.hr_HR'), 
    pri.amount, 
    cur.java_currency, 
    cou.alpha2,
    JSON_EXTRACT(cit.name, '$.hr_HR'),
    pri.local_date_time_valid_from, 
    pri.local_date_time_valid_to, 
    pri.zone_id_valid_from_to
FROM article art
LEFT JOIN price_info      pri ON pri.article_id = art.id
LEFT JOIN provider        pro ON pro.id         = pri.provider_id 
LEFT JOIN city            cit ON cit.id         = pro.city_id
LEFT JOIN country         cou ON cou.id         = cit.country_id
LEFT JOIN custom_currency cur ON cur.id         = pri.currency_id
WHERE 
    cou.alpha2 = 'DE'
    AND
    pri.amount IS NOT NULL
    AND (
        pri.local_date_time_valid_from IS NULL
        OR
        pri.local_date_time_valid_from >= STR_TO_DATE('2021-01-01','%Y-%m-%d')
    )
    AND (
        pri.local_date_time_valid_to IS NULL
        OR
        pri.local_date_time_valid_to <= STR_TO_DATE('2022-01-01','%Y-%m-%d')
    );
```

Comment: @andrewJames yes, I know that. Data is actually stored in MySQL but as I have more than 30 tables in model, Hibernate creates quite a large queries which are slow. So far I managed all critical queries through Lucene and it works pretty well. This one is for now Lucene query without date ranges, but if I filter out articles afterwards, page size could change. You can check speed here: https://thevegcat.com

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to index Article entities in order to issue a search which will return only articles that has active prices (which would be "permanent" prices without dates and also prices that match date range based on current or any other given date).

With Hibernate Search 6, yes. You will need [nested documents](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexedembedded-structure), so that when searching you can express the intent "I want today to be between the start date and end date of the *same* price, and that *same* price must be for country DE".

With Hibernate Search 5, I don't know of a solution.

Comment: That's great news! So far tried to upgrade to 6 two times and both times no luck because of mess with Jakarta package names. But I'll do it for sure.

Comment: There is no jakarta package name mess with Hibernate Search 6. Hibernate Search 6 works with Hibernate ORM 5. You're thinking of Hibernate ORM 6.

Comment: Well yes, I tried to upgrade them both. But as I use many indexing bridges, there was lack of replacements so I had to write this part from scratch and finally gave up and added to TODO list. And I wanted to avoid migration helper dependeny also.